# I need help with a simple proof for the associative law of scalar multiplication of a vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I need help with a simple proof for  the associative law of scalar

multiplication of a vectors. If

$$(rs)X =r (sX)$$

Define the elements belonging to $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $\{(a,b)|a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Combining elements within this set under the operations of vector addition and scalar multiplication should use the following notation:

Vector Addition Example: 
$$(–2,10)+(–5,0)=(–2–5,10+0)=(–7,10)$$
Scalar Multiplication Example:

$$–10×(1,–7)=(–10×1,–10×–7)=(–10,70)$$ 
where –10 is a scalar.

Comment: How are you defining vectors and scalar multiplication? What are you allowed to assume in the proof?

Comment: The proof depend from the vector space in which you are working, and the definition of the scalar multiplication in this space. So, what is your vector space?

Comment: ector spaces possess a collection of specific characteristics and properties. Use the definitions in the attached “Definitions” to complete this task.

Define the elements belonging to R2 as {(a,b)|a,b∈R}. Combining elements within this set under the operations of vector addition and scalar multiplication should use the following notation:

Vector Addition Example: (–2,10)+(–5,0)=(–2–5,10+0)=(–7,10)
Scalar Multiplication Example: –10×(1,–7)=(–10×1,–10×–7)=(–10,70), where –10 is a scalar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question, it appears you are only interested in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but in case not, we'll do the proof over $\mathbb{R}^n$.  (If you only want $\mathbb{R}^2$, then set $n=2$ in what follows, or replace $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ by $(x,y)$.)  (Of course, this law holds much more generally, but to keep things concrete we'll just be concerned with real numbers and $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

Let $X = (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ be a vector, $r,s$ scalars.  Then,
\begin{align*}
  (rs)X &= (rs)(x_1, \ldots, x_n)\\
 &= ((rs)x_1, (rs)x_2, \ldots, (rs)x_n) & (\text{Def. of scalar mult.})\\
 &= (r(sx_1), r(sx_2), \ldots, r(sx_n)) & (\text{Assoc. law in } \mathbb{R})\\
 &= r (sx_1, sx_2, \ldots, sx_n) & (\text{Def. of scalar mult. by } r) \\
 &= r(s(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) & (\text{Def. of scalar mult. by } s) \\
 &= r(sX) & (\text{substituting in our def. of } X)
\end{align*}

The key step (and really the only one that is not from the definition of scalar multiplication) is once you have $((rs)x_1, \ldots, (rs)x_n)$ you realize that each element $(rs)x_i$ is a product of three real numbers.  Since you have the associative law in $\mathbb{R}$ you can use that to write
$$ (rs)x_i = r(sx_i). $$